# Do classical singing techniques make low notes harder to sing?

Tags: voice

I've been thinking about singing low notes and classical technique.

I sing at church and some melodies go from C3-C4.
The other men seem to have no issue with that range. I am not sure they use as much classical technique as I do.

When I use classical techniques E3-E4 feel much easier.
I feel that C3 is hard to sing if I use proper classical techniques.

C3 felt easier before I took classical singing lessons.

Do classical singing techniques make low notes harder to sing?

Comment: It might just be that you can't produce the level of tone on the lower C that you can on the higher notes, now you've started to train. You're probably also more aware of the pitch and tone you're producing, so you're singing harder to achieve it.

Comment: It feels much lower after I have been taking  singing lessons. Proper techniques makes lower notes harder it seems. So for church  music classical techniques won't work?

Comment: Lessons on any instrument, including voice, develops both our ability on the instrument or voice **and** our ears. So perhaps your sound on C3 hasn't changed that much and instead your awareness of your weakness on C3 has developed as you've taken lessons. It's also possible that proper technique makes some things "more difficult" but only because it's easier to do those things *with poor technique*. So do you want to sing C3 easily or do you want to sing it very well, with good tone, etc.?

Comment: Not an answer, but an anecdote: I know a few people (men and women) who've said similar things. They've said their low range has become more difficult to sing in since they started taking lessons. They also believe the tonal quality of their low range has worsened. I also know a former classical singer (with a degree in music/voice) who said she used to be able to sing much lower, but lost all of her notes below A3 after classical training. Apparently it rebalances the voice

Answer (score 2):

”Proper“ technique should enable you to sing both high and low. But often beginners will have problems to adapt their vocal configuration for these different situations.

Essentially you need to adapt the resonance and how much the vocal muscles vibrate (as compared to only the vocal cords vibrating). The more the vocal muscle vibrates the higher the mass gets, which will result in a more powerful, heavier and lower voice.

I suppose you are currently keeping your voice in a configuration suited for middle range to high notes, which will essentially make it impossible to sing lower notes.

Comment: What is the definition of middle range?